# How can I reset tintColor of UINavigationItem.BackBarButtonItem?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

Let's say we have a root controller X (for a navigation controller) from which we can navigate through other two view controllers (A and B); I would like to set a specific color for the back button shown in the controller A and use the default transparent(?) color for the back button (the same, I know) shown in the controller B.

Since the back button for controllers A and B is set in controller X, I can easily change the color when controller A is shown; however I cannot reset the color when controller B appear.

With the other BarButtonItem (e.g. right one) I simply re-create the button and re-assign to xxxBarButtonItem property; but with the back button this doesn't work... any clue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your app delegate set a property that gets the default color on application load. Then get back that value when you need it.

Comment: Unfortunately, the default value is null and it is not allowed to assign null to TintColor property of UIBarButtonItems.

Comment: Try [UIColor colorWithHue:0.6 saturation:0.33 brightness:0.69 alpha:0]

Comment: What about changing the "0" to "0.0"

Comment: OK, now I see why hue, saturation and brightness are not 0: it looks like the default color.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because the back button is a system item. System items can't be tinted. Your only option would be to override the back button with a custom image and code the button yourself. You will run into this issue on right bar button items as well if you use any of the pre-supplied system item. (eg Done, Add, etc)

Comment: Actually, I don't have any problem to change and reset the tintColor of left and right bar button item (system item too!); I think the problem is specifically bounded to the back button which it seems accept only not-null color!

Comment: Wait! Maybe I understand why you are so sure that I cannot do what I'm actually doing: I'm working with iOS 5... trying to change the tintColor in the same application with iOS 4.3 it throws an exception!

Comment: You can set the default tint with `[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];`